# Nested Routes in emberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have the following routes:

```
@resource 'menus', (->
  @resource 'menu', {path: ':menu_id'}, ( ->
    @resource 'menu_pages', ( ->
      @resource 'menu_page', {path: ':menu_page_id'}
    )
  )
)
```

and I am trying to transition to a nested route as follows:

```
firstMenuPage = App.MenuPage.find(1)
@transitionToRoute 'menu_page', firstMenuPage
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.
```

Anyone know what is going on?

thanks

Comment: This seems to be related to your store rather than the route

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll investigate more

Comment: Can you add the code of your store and model definition?

Comment: I am using the localStorage adapter here: https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter here is the store code: `App.store = DS.Store.create
  revision: 11
  adapter: DS.LSAdapter.create()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, you can do it by passing the two required models in the nesting:

```
#transition to first menu page
firstMenu = App.Menu.find().objectAt(0)
firstMenuPage = firstMenu.get('menu_pages').objectAt(0)
@transitionToRoute 'menu_page', firstMenu, firstMenuPage
```